# Export Highcharts code from jsfiddle

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I need to export the code for Highcharts from jsfiddle to my local file. Here's the chart code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/yaxis-plotlines/
It works nice on jsfiddle, but when I put it in my local file and open in a browser, chart isn't displayed. I get code from jsfiddle using "View frame source" and here's what I get:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
  <meta name="googlebot" content="noindex, nofollow">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">


  <style type="text/css">

  </style>

  <title></title>


<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

$(function () {
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        var startDate = new Date(data[data.length - 1][0]), // Get year of last data point
            minRate = 1,
            maxRate = 0,
            startPeriod,
            date,
            rate,
            index;

        startDate.setMonth(startDate.getMonth() - 3); // a quarter of a year before last data point
        startPeriod = Date.UTC(startDate.getFullYear(), startDate.getMonth(), startDate.getDate());

        for (index = data.length - 1; index >= 0; index = index - 1) {
            date = data[index][0]; // data[i][0] is date
            rate = data[index][1]; // data[i][1] is exchange rate
            if (date < startPeriod) {
                break; // stop measuring highs and lows
            }
            if (rate > maxRate) {
                maxRate = rate;
            }
            if (rate < minRate) {
                minRate = rate;
            }
        }

        // Create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
            },

            title: {
                text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate'
            },

            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Exchange rate'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: minRate,
                    color: 'green',
                    dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                    width: 2,
                    label: {
                        text: 'Last quarter minimum'
                    }
                }, {
                    value: maxRate,
                    color: 'red',
                    dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                    width: 2,
                    label: {
                        text: 'Last quarter maximum'
                    }
                }]
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'USD to EUR',
                data: data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 4
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
//]]> 

</script>


</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

So it only shows blank page. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Probably trying to open file instead of running it on server. Can't use ajax in `file://` protocol. Your code [works fine exactly as is here](http://plnkr.co/edit/MdY8rNAodV7szOPV6v71?p=preview)

Comment: File is loaded from Highcharts website (according to the OP code) so it shouldn't be a problem. @TheCyberNash could you tell us if you have any errors in JS console?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine locally after adding `<base href="http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/yaxis-plotlines" />` into the head. Don't know why but it solved the problem.